# How to adjust aspect video layer after scale it down in Tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Sorry if i ask silly question, i am noob with tailwind. I have html code which is using tailwindcss as framework. This is my script:

```
<div class="columns has-background-grey-lighter">
        <div class="column is-2 has-background-white relative">
            <div id="slides" class="mt-9">
                <div v-for="(slide, index) in orderedSlide" :key="slide.no" class="relative overflow-hidden w-full h-24 aspect-video">
                    <div class="absolute inset-0 left-0 right-0 transform scale-[0.25] w-full">
                    <p class="title">HARAPAN BANGSA DIDEPAN MATA</p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <!-- OTHERS -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is how it looks
[image: views]

If you look on my inner text (tag p), it doesn't fit the full width. However it parent has much space. How to make the inner adjust the parent width?

FYI, i use mix library Bulma and TailwindCSS, `column`, `columns`, `has-background-grey-lighter` coming from bulma